# PHP Convert a string into array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an archive from a program, i need the info of this archive loaded in php as an array.

I can set the info of the archive in a string but I cant convert it into an array.

This is the string:

```
archivedVars =
{
    ["Default"] = 
    {
        ["Name"] = 
        {
            ["Name1"] = 
            {
                ["@XXXXX"] = 
                {
                    ["show"] = true,
                    ["open"] = true,
                },
            },
            ["Name2"] = 
            {
                ["YYYYY"] = 
                {
                    ["show"] = true,
                    ["open"] = true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

How can I convert this string into an php array?

Comment: Why is the JSON invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing would be to discover what format is used and what decoding libraries exist.

Failing that, you should develop a proper parser, using e.g. a state machine or something.

If the structure is as you posted, and structure correctness is assured, you might try and transform it in something parsable by available libraries, e.g. JSON:

```
$str = preg_replace('#[[]("[^"]+")[]]\\s*=#', '\\1:', $str);
$str = preg_replace('#,(\\s*})#', '\\1', $str);
$str = preg_replace('#archivedVars =#', '', $str);
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
```

The above (even if you should never parse HTML - or structured data - with regexps) will yield a walkable array:

```
Array
(
    [Default] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Array
                (
                    [Name1] => Array
                        (
                            [@XXXXX] => Array
                                (
                                    [show] => 1
                                    [open] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [Name2] => Array
                        (
                            [YYYYY] => Array
                                (
                                    [show] => 1
                                    [open] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Good Job! I was trying to figure out the same, but way too fast for me!